# Как написать команду grep для примера?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Нужно вывести те строки в которых есть телефонные номера . Номера в строках такого вида `095-678-453`. Я написала `grep '...-...-...' file.txt` но у меня выводиться ещё одна строка такого вида `1879 N. Kellogg Dr`. Что не правильно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ```grep -E '[0-9]{3,3}-[0-9]{3,3}-[0-9]{3,3}'```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: `grep -P '([0-9]{3})(-[0-9]{3}){2}'` можно попробовать еще так